# Inconsistant return with __get magic function and empty function

Tags: php

Let's say I have this code:

```
$test = $model->contacts;
$test2 = $model->__get('contacts');
$test3 = !empty($test2);
$test4 = !empty($test);
$test5 = !empty($model->contacts);
```

Where the `__get` magic function is quite simple:

```
public function __get($prop)
{
    return isset($this->properties[$prop]) ? $this->properties[$prop] : null;
}
```

How is it possible to have these returned values?

```
$test => App\Models\Contacts[1]
$test2 => App\Models\Contacts[1]
$test3 => true
$test4 => true
$test5 => false
```

If I store the result in a variable (`$test`) empty is returning `false`, if I call it directly (`$test5`) it's returning `true`.

Is there something I missed with the `empty` function or the `__get` magic function?

Comment: `__get` is a magic method and should not be called explicitly.

Comment: I know it's just to describe my problem

Comment: `__get() is utilized for reading data from inaccessible (protected or private) or non-existing properties` is `properties` protected or private?

Comment: `$properties` is protected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose your case described in note to [`empty`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php#refsect1-function.empty-notes):

> When using `empty()` on inaccessible object properties, the `__isset()` overloading method will be called, if declared.

So, everything is correct - instead of receiving value using `__get()`, `empty` just checks if property is defined. For correct result you should define `__isset` in your class with some logic like:

```
public function __isset($prop)
{
    return !empty($this->properties[$prop]);
}
```

Comment: For the record, using `empty` in the function was not the answer, but I had to use `isset`: `return isset($this->properties[$prop]);`